# mysql optimize stored procedure insert

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, optimization

This is my first stored procedure so I am not sure I am doing this correctly. I have tried to optimize this as much as I can but still end up with a query timeout at 10 minutes of running. I really need this to scale even higher than what I am working with currently. Any assistance would be great.

I have a decent sized data set (108K rows) and one of the fields contains a comma delimited list (I wish the engineers hadn't done this). I need to break apart that field so each entry is on it's own row AND all other fields are assigned to that row as well. I have developed a stored procedure that loops through the table row by row then breaks apart the field and inserts it into a second table.

Here is the code I have used:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dwh_inventory.nas_share_temp;

CREATE TABLE dwh_inventory.nas_share_temp (
    share_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    fileShareId int(11) NOT NULL,
    storageId int(11) NOT NULL,
    identifier varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    protocol enum('CIFS','NFS') NOT NULL,
    ipInterfaces VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dwh_inventory.share_step;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dwh_inventory.share_step()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE strLen    INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE SubStrLen INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE ip VARCHAR(20);
        SET autocommit = 0;
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dwh_inventory.nas_share INTO n;
        SET i=0;
        WHILE i<n DO 
            SELECT id, fileShareId, storageId, identifier, name, protocol, ipInterfaces  
                INTO @share_id, @fileShareId, @storageId, @identifier, @name, @protocol, @ipInterfaces 
                FROM dwh_inventory.nas_share LIMIT i,1;
            IF @ipInterfaces IS NULL THEN
                SET @ipInterfaces = '';
            END IF;
            do_this:
            LOOP
                SET strLen = CHAR_LENGTH(@ipInterfaces);
                SET ip = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@ipInterfaces, ',', 1);                
                INSERT INTO dwh_inventory.nas_share_temp 
                    (share_id, fileShareId, storageId, identifier,name,protocol,ipInterfaces)
                    VALUES (@share_id, 
                            @fileShareId, 
                            @storageId,
                            @identifier,
                            @name,
                            @protocol,
                            ip
                            );
                SET SubStrLen = CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@ipInterfaces, ',', 1)) + 2;
                SET @ipInterfaces = MID(@ipInterfaces, SubStrLen, strLen);
                IF @ipInterfaces = '' THEN
                    LEAVE do_this;
                END IF;
            END LOOP do_this;
            COMMIT;
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET autocommit = 1;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL dwh_inventory.share_step();
```

Example of the data:

```
id,fileShareId,storageId,identifier,name,protocol,ipInterfaces
1325548,1128971,33309,/vol/vol0/:NFS,/vol/vol0/,NFS,"10.66.213.118,10.68.208.76"
1325549,1128991,33309,/vol/vol0/:NFS,/vol/vol0/,NFS,"10.66.213.119,10.68.208.77"
1325550,1128992,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/EPS_ROOT/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/EPS_ROOT/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325551,1128993,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/GCO_Report/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/GCO_Report/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325552,1128995,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/PI/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/PI/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325553,1128996,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/a/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/a/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325554,1128997,33325,/vol/aggr1_64_sapserv/:NFS,/vol/aggr1_64_sapserv/,NFS,147.204.2.13
1325555,1128999,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325556,1129001,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/central/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/central/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325557,1129004,33325,/vol/nsvfm0079b_E5V/db_clients/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0079b_E5V/db_clients/,NFS,"10.21.188.161,10.70.151.93"
1325558,1129006,33325,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/istrans/:NFS,/vol/aggr2_64_hs2032/istrans/,NFS,10.17.124.10
1325559,1129008,33325,/vol/nsvfm0017_DEWDFGLD00603/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0017_DEWDFGLD00603/,NFS,"10.21.188.115,10.70.151.138"
1325560,1129009,33325,/vol/nsvfm0017_vol0/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0017_vol0/,NFS,"10.21.188.115,10.70.151.138"
1325561,1129011,33325,/vol/nsvfm0017a_ls2278/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0017a_ls2278/,NFS,"10.21.188.115,10.70.151.138"
1325562,1129015,33325,/vol/nsvfm0051passive_vol0/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0051passive_vol0/,NFS,10.17.144.249
1325563,1129017,33325,/vol/nsvfm0053_vol0/:NFS,/vol/nsvfm0053_vol0/,NFS,"10.21.189.251,10.70.151.109"
```

Comment: would it take more than 10 minutes to write an automated script to save the data as non-CSV ?

Answer (score 0):

- InnoDB tables must have a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- `LIMIT i,1` will get slower and slower as you go through the table -- it hast to skip over `i` rows before finding the one you need.
- Don't try to split comma-separated text in SQL; use a real language (PHP / Perl / etc).  Or, as Lew suggests, write out that column, then use `LOAD DATA` to bring it into another table.
- `LIMIT` should be preceded by an `ORDER BY`.